# SSRS Report Viewer Control Display Issues

Tags: reporting-services, report-viewer2010, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that is now displayed via an ASPX report viewer control (VS2010). It was previously displayed via Report Builder 3.

The browser is the same, IE8, but the report is now NOT displaying vertical text

Is there an issue with the control and is there a fix or a workaround? The report now looks very poor!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using WrintingMode = Vertical in you report?

Comment: Writing mode is Rotate270 and it is only actually a problem visually in the control i.e. it exports to PDF fine and prints fine!

Comment: There was a bug that was fixed a while back. The work around use to be to write code to rotate images rendered based on your text. As far as I know that issue has been resolved a while back.

Comment: @RossBush i am having the same exact issue now. I am using VS2010 (version 4.5) are you still aware of a workaround for this?

Comment: DID YOU EVER RESOLVE THIS @72GM??

Comment: @Koosh - I don't have my code on that as I migrated away a while back, however, here is a blog that still contains the solution -->http://sqljason.com/2011/01/rotate-text-in-ssrs.html